# Passing Item from ListBox to procedure

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I want to select a specific user from a listbox that is in a form, and pass that user to the procedure.  The listbox is populated by a query that pulls the names from a Personnel table into the listbox.

I am finding(I am assuming) that in the procedure, I am getting all the users sent to the procedure based on that when I run a debug.print command:

```
Debug.Print  Me.ListBox.ItemData(0)
Debug.Print  Me.ListBox.ItemData(1)
Debug.Print  Me.ListBox.ItemData(2)
```

in the Immediate Window, I get each of the users--User01, User02, User03.

As an example, I want to select User02 in the listbox, and only have that user's name sent to the procedure.

I have included the requery command at the beginning of the procedure, Me.ListBox.Requery, but it doesn't seem to be querying and selecting the selected user's name from the listbox.

I realize this is a very basic process, but I have not been able to find this specific question in the forums, thanks for all your help--

CTR

Comment: Is the user you want selected? Is the listbox multi-select? Can you include some sample code?

Comment: I can scroll to the user I want to select but it doesn't seem to select/capture that name, all users are being sent to the procedure; the listbox is not multi-select; and there is no real code in the form where the listbox isPrivate Sub btn_Q1_Click()


Me.AM_SS.Requery


Dim x As Long


Debug.Print "Data from AM_SS0 textbox: " & Me.AM_SS.ItemData(0)
Debug.Print "Data from AM_SS1 textbox: " & Me.AM_SS.ItemData(1)
Debug.Print "Data from AM_SS2 textbox: " & Me.AM_SS.ItemData(2)
Debug.Print "Data from AM_SS3 textbox: " & Me.AM_SS.ItemData(3)

Comment: Ok, that was embarrassing!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is to return the currently selected user:

```
Debug.Print  Me!ListBox.Value
```